# ASP Classic: Cookie keys not readable after modifying cookie string

Tags: c#, cookies, asp-classic

I have an application with a mix of ASP Classic and .NET that shares cookies with keys.  For example: `c = request.cookies("LS")("course_int")`.

Turns out ASP stores underscores as `%5F` in the cookie so .NET changes them before reading.  Occasionally, something goes wrong and I am unable to find out where or how, but the underscore becomes `%265F` and neither app can read them.

I tried reading the whole cookie, e.g., `c=request.cookies("LS")`, modifying the whole string `c` by removing the key `course_int`, and writing it back: `response.cookie("LS") = c`.

When I read the cookie again, `c=request.cookies("LS")`, is present but if I try to read a key (any key!) e.g., `request.cookies("LS")("person_int")`, the keys are empty!  Cookie `length` has the right value but I can no longer access the key values by key name.

What's happening and how can I write the cookie after modification so I can access it's keys normally?

Comment: `%26` is the sign for `&` so it looks like somewhere the `%5F` gets converted to `&5F`and then that in turn converts to `%265F`. Could it be that you have something like `replace(string, '_','&5F')` accidentally instead of `replace(string, '_','%5F')`?

Comment: Great thought!  I'll look through the code and see if I can find anything like that!

Comment: Did you manage to get this solved?

Comment: Sort of solved it by using AJAX to call a page that clears the cookie domain.  I never found out how/why I got the %265F but did notice that every once in a while the domain /lmw got added.  That's when things went bad so that's the cookie I had to delete.  Only way to do that without killing the / domain was a separate page.